# How to convert R Markdown to PDF?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I've previously asked about the [commands for converting R Markdown to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10646665/180892).

**What is a good way to convert R Markdown files to PDF documents?**

A good solution would preserve as much as possible of the content (e.g., images, equations, html tables, etc.). The solution needs to be able to be run from the command-line. A good solution would also be cross-platform, and ideally minimise dependencies to make it easier to share makefiles and so forth.

Specifically, there are a lot of options:

- Whether to convert RMD to MD to HTML to PDF; or RMD to MD to PDF; or RMD to PDF
- If using the `markdown` package in R, which options to specify
- Whether to use `pandoc`, a package built into R, or something else

Here's an example [rmd file](https://gist.github.com/jeromyanglim/2716336) that presumably provides a reasonable test of any proposed solution. It was used as the basis for [this blog post](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/getting-started-with-r-markdown-knitr.html).

Comment: I believe pandoc should be the best way to go. It does not make much sense to me to build it into R, and I do not think it is possible either (it is written in Haskell). I have some very early work here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-book (see two shell scripts `knit` and `mdconvert.sh`). It may be hard to come up a general approach since LaTeX is too flexible; you can use all kinds of templates for pandoc.

Comment: What is 'R Markdown*? http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/r_markdown

Comment: http://www.markdowntopdf.com/ this site is pretty good, actually. However, there is no latex support

Comment: Can we update this answer for RStudio v1.0?

Answer (score 74):

#### Updated Answer (10 Feb 2013)

**rmarkdown package**: 
There is now an [`rmarkdown` package available on github](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown) that interfaces with Pandoc. 
It includes a `render` function. The documentation makes it pretty clear how to convert rmarkdown to pdf among a range of other formats. This includes including output formats in the rmarkdown file or running supplying an output format to the rend function. E.g.,

```
render("input.Rmd", "pdf_document")
```

**Command-line:**
When I run `render` from the command-line (e.g., using a makefile), I sometimes have issues with pandoc not being found. Presumably, it is not on the search path.
The following answer explains [how to add pandoc to the R environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710643/180892).

So for example, on my computer running OSX, where I have a copy of pandoc through RStudio, I can use the following:

```
Rscript -e "Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC='/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc');library(rmarkdown);  library(utils); render('input.Rmd', 'pdf_document')"
```

---

#### Old Answer (circa 2012)

So, a number of people have suggested that Pandoc is the way to go. See notes below about the importance of having an up-to-date version of Pandoc.

#### Using Pandoc

I used the following command to convert R Markdown to HTML (i.e., [a variant of this makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10969107/180892)), where `RMDFILE` is the name of the R Markdown file without the `.rmd` component (it also assumes that the extension is `.rmd` and not `.Rmd`).

```
RMDFILE=example-r-markdown  
Rscript -e "require(knitr); require(markdown); knit('$RMDFILE.rmd', '$RMDFILE.md'); markdownToHTML('$RMDFILE.md', '$RMDFILE.html', options=c('use_xhml'))"
```

and then this command to convert to pdf

```
Pandoc -s example-r-markdown.html -o example-r-markdown.pdf
```

---

A few notes about this:

- I removed the reference in the example file which exports plots to imgur to host images.
- I removed a reference to an image that was hosted on imgur. Figures appear to need to be local.
- The options in the `markdownToHTML` function meant that image references are to files and not to data stored in the HTML file (i.e., I removed `'base64_images'` from the option list).
- The resulting output looked like [this](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/jeromyanglim/assorted-files/example-r-markdown.pdf). It has clearly made a very LaTeX style document in contrast to what I get if I print the HTML file to pdf from a browser.

#### Getting up-to-date version of Pandoc

As mentioned by @daroczig, it's important to have an up-to-date version of Pandoc in order to output pdfs. On Ubuntu as of 15th June 2012, I was stuck with version 1.8.1 of Pandoc in the package manager, but it seems from the [change log](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/releases.html) that for pdf support you need at least version 1.9+ of Pandoc.

Thus, I installed `caball-install`. 
And then ran:

```
cabal update
cabal install pandoc
```

Pandoc was installed in `~/.cabal/bin/pandoc`
Thus, when I ran `pandoc` it was still seeing the old version.
See here for [adding to the path](https://askubuntu.com/a/33443/2521).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just want to comment that my experience was that giving the .md file to *pandoc*, rather than the .html file, gave a better output. So it's worth to experiment.

Comment: This is the closest I've come to a good process as well. Is there any way of changing the figure text from "plot chunk of ..." to something else?

Comment: `pandoc` is in version 1.12 even in my now outdated Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 23):

I think you really need [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which great software was designed and built just for this task :) Besides *pdf*, you could convert your *md* file to e.g. *docx* or *odt* among others.

Well, [installing an up-to-date version of Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) might be challanging on Linux (as you would need the entire `haskell-platform`˙to build from the sources), but really easy on Windows/Mac with only a few megabytes of download.

If you have the brewed/knitted markdown file you can just call `pandoc` in e.g bash or with the `system` function within R. A POC demo of that latter is implemented in the [`Ṗandoc.convert` function of my little package](https://github.com/rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/convert.R#L28) (*which you must be terribly bored of as I try to point your attention there at every opportunity*).

Comment: +1 The function looks good; Do you have a recommended one-liner pandoc command for converting R Markdown to PDF?

Comment: Adding `--toc` would be useful on the command line (resulting in a nics table of content based on your headings) and also customizing the LaTeX template for your needs (like adding there `\listoffigures` and/or `\listoftables` etc.) could result in wonderful documents.

Comment: What challenging about `apt-get install pandoc` ?

Comment: @sumid you might have missed the **up-to-date** part (well, if you are not using testing).

Comment: Yeah you're right - twice. I missed it and I'm also using testing ;-) Then I perceive as easier temporary allowing testing in `sources.list` and doing `apt-get install -t testing pandoc` then installing `haskell-platform` and compilation. (Usually I do this  with experimental. I hope is works the same way in testing.)

Comment: As `pandoc` depends on some core or quite standard packages too (like `glibc6`, `texlive` etc.), it can be a real pain to install/update the package from `testing`. I mean I have ended up with some systems with installed packages from `stable` and also from `testing` before, and I did not like to do a dist-update at all on those machines :) That's possible, but I rather compile `pandoc` in my `$HOME`. Either way: it can get complicated from a POV :(

Comment: @daroczig, your "Pandoc.convert function of my little package" link is broken.

Comment: Thanks @GSee for pointing my attention here, just update the link.

Answer (score 15):

Right now (August 2014) You could use **RStudio** for converting R Markdown to PDF. 
Basically, RStudio use **pandoc** to convert Rmd to PDF.

You could change metadata to:

1. Add table of contents
2. Change figure options
3. Change syntax highlighting style
4. Add LaTeX options
5. And many more...

For more details - http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html[image]

Comment: 'knit PDF' option is not available in the Ubuntu 14.04, pandoc v1.17.1. Is there any settings needs to be done?

Comment: What version of RStudio do you have? Did you create a new rmarkdown file?

Comment: Rstudio - v 0.98.507

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116818/discussion-between-prradep-and-jot-en).

Comment: @Prradep What was the result of the conversation?

Answer (score 10):

For an option that looks more like what you get when you print from a browser, [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) provides one option.

On Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

And then the same command as for the pandoc example to get to the HTML:

```
RMDFILE=example-r-markdown  
Rscript -e "require(knitr); require(markdown); knit('$RMDFILE.rmd', '$RMDFILE.md'); markdownToHTML('$RMDFILE.md', '$RMDFILE.html', options=c('use_xhml'))"
```

and then

```
wkhtmltopdf example-r-markdown.html example-r-markdown.pdf
```

The resulting file looked like [this](https://github.com/downloads/jeromyanglim/assorted-files/example-r-markdown-wk.pdf). It did not seem to handle the MathJax ([this issue is discussed here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=728)), and the page breaks are ugly. However, in some cases, such a style might be preferred over a more LaTeX style presentation.

Comment: I am unable to run the last command in RStudio. 
I have tried 
`system("wkhtmltopdf temp.html temp.pdf")`

Any idea how to fix that

Answer (score 10):

Only two steps:

1. Install the latest release "pandoc" from here:

   https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases
2. Call the function `pandoc` in the `library(knitr)`

   ```
   library(knitr)
   pandoc('input.md', format = 'latex')
   ```

Thus, you can convert your "input.md" into "input.pdf".

Answer (score 4):

I found using R studio the easiest way, but if wanting to control from the command line, then a simple R script can do the trick using [rmarkdown](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/index.html) render command (as mentioned above).  Full script details [here](http://frankhjung.blogspot.com.au/2016/08/render-r-markdown-to-pdf-from-command.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env R

# Render R markdown to PDF.
# Invoke with:
# > R -q -f make.R --args my_report.Rmd

# load packages
require(rmarkdown)

# require a parameter naming file to render
if (length(args) == 0) {
    stop("Error: missing file operand", call. = TRUE)
} else {
    # read report to render from command line
    for (rmd in commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)) {
        # render Rmd to PDF
        if ( grepl("\\.Rmd$", rmd) && file.exists(rmd)) {
            render(rmd, pdf_document())
        } else {
            print(paste("Ignoring: ", rmd))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these simple  steps :

1: In the Rmarkdown script run Knit(Ctrl+Shift+K) 
2: Then after the html markdown is opened click Open in Browser(top left side) and 
   the html is opened in your web browser
3: Then use Ctrl+P and save as PDF .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install anything you can output html. Then open the html file - it should open in a browser window, then right click to print. In the print window, select "save as pdf" in the bottom right hand corner if you're on a Mac. Voila!