# How to specify a global path to pandoc in R rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I am using R rmarkdown package to render `.Rmd` file to the `html` output.
This package is using `pandoc` to convert `.md` file to `html` as I've understood. Under my `CentOS` machine with version as below

```
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core) 
cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
```

I have a `pandoc` with a version

```
-bash-4.2$ pandoc --version
pandoc 1.12.4.2
```

But when I run `rmarkdown::render()` function I receive such an error

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found.
Execution halted
```

I think `R` is using it's local pandoc which looks like it's older that my global pandoc. Does anyone know how to specify a global path to the global `pandoc` in `R rmarkdown`  ?

Comment: R you using RStudio?

Comment: Check this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny) or this [one](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-August/421215.html).

Comment: @Michał I am using shell.

Comment: As @langusta suggested, I used this answer and it worked http://stackoverflow.com/a/29710643/3857701 .

Answer (score 0):

As @langusta suggested, I used this answer and it worked: [pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (R shiny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny/29710643#29710643)