# Pandoc while using R markdown with a cron command

Tags: r, cron, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to create a cron command that will use R markdown to create a new html page at specified intervals. I've discovered this is a pandoc issue.

I get the following error message when I log my cron command

> Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found
>   (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available). Execution halted

Is there a simple bit of code I can add **to the .Rmd file** to point it to pandoc when executing the cron command?

---

Preserving the original post. That is below this paragraph.

Everything I want to do is a a file titled `test_doc.Rmd`.

When I run the following command on the command line, it works successfully:

```
RScript -e "library(rmarkdown); render(\"/path/test_doc.Rmd\")"
```

However, when I run that in the crontab, I'm having no success. I'm running a version of this:

```
25      10      *       *       *       RScript -e "library(rmarkdown); render(\"/path/test_doc.Rmd\")"
```

I'm baffled. I don't believe it's a filepath issue, since I have other R scripts (not rmarkdown) running in the crontab and working. I am on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Comment: Was wondering if you ever managed to solve this

Answer (score 5):

The same has happened to me, and I found the answer in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny) regarding your error message (which I haven't even seen):

> Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available). Execution halted

You have to specify the RSTUDIO_PANDOC environment variable before rendering like so:

```
Rscript -e 'Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc"); rmarkdown::render("test_doc.Rmd")'
```

This should solve your cronjob issue. It worked for me.

I am assuming that most Linux+RStudio users have pandoc installed in this /usr/... path. Otherwise, query the location using `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")` from an interactive session where the knitting works, and substitute the path in the above command.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
25 10 * * *   cd /path && Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("test_doc.Rmd")'
```

which avoids

1. The full path and gives rmarkdown and knitr a better working directory
2. The need to 'quote quotes' by having apostrophes on the outside and standard double quotes on the inside.

Comment: I am still not getting this to work in the crontab (it does in terminal). Might it be a permissions issue? Or issue with the packages?

Comment: Do you use `/etc/crontab` or a per user crontab?  I _always_ start by just `touch /tmp/BeenHereNowDeleteMe.txt` or some such and build up from there.

Comment: I've been on a per user crontab.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the beginning of your cron, and redirect the output for debugging purposes:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

*/5 * * * * cd /path/to/script/ && Rscript -e 'library(rmarkdown); rmarkdown::render("your_script.Rmd")' >/path/to/script/cron.log 2>/path/to/script/cronerr.log
```