# Need help assigning global settings for Rstudio's pandoc in VSCode to knit pdf_document in a .rmd output format

Tags: visual-studio-code, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

So I am migrating from RStudio to Visual Studio Code for my future R projects. I have successfully gotten my github aspect all setup and I am trying to write my code in (.rmd) format so that I can knit it to pdf, html and flex_dashboard outputs. When I have tried to knit the it, I get the following error:

> rmarkdown::render("c:\Users\{user}\{folder}\{sub-folder}\{sub-folder}\Co$
>
> Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).>

I found the following solution that once run in the terminal, allows it to knit into a pdf_document successfully.

> Code: Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="--- insert directory here ---")
>
> Reference: [pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (R shiny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny)

This is great, but everytime I restart VSCode, this setting appears to be reset and I have to run it again. Is there away to set this globally so that I don't have to run it every time I use it? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem before in VScode to render R markdown. Now, I found the solutions to it.

Following the steps below to properly set up the pandoc:

#### Step 1:

Go to your R Studio and go the console, type the following:

```
Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")
```

If you are using MacOS, you will get the path for "pandoc": `"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"`

If you are using Windows, you probably will get the path like:
`"/c/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/"` as mentioned in [pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (R shiny)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny)

#### Step 2:

Paste the path of "pandoc" and put it into your bash or zsh (depends on what command shell that you are using).

- On MacOS, I'm using `zsh`. Therefore, I add the following path into `~/.zshrc`:

```
export RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"
```

As for how to edit `~/.zshrc`, one way to do this is presented as follows:

**step 2.1**

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

It will open your `.zshrc` file and navigate to the bottom of this file, paste the

`export RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"`. Then, `control` + `X` to exit. It will ask about "Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?", then type `Y` and type `return` bottom.

**step 2.2**

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now, it should work fine in VScode. By checking if it works, you could open your console by typing `R` to invoke the R environment and type `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`. If it returns the path of the "pandoc", it would work fine in VScode as well.

Comment: On a Mac, I think `Sys.getenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC)` is now located `"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin")`

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "RSTUDIO_PANDOC":"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"
    }
```

into settings.json worked for me.
Adding to .zshrc didn't work at all since the System environment wasn't being passed on to the integrated terminal.