# rmarkdown::render() in cmd returns pandoc error

Tags: r, cmd, markdown, pandoc

I need to render forms with rmarkdown from a command line

this is where I am:

- knit button in RStudio works fine
- function `rmarkdown::render(file.rmd)` in a .r file works when run in Rstudio

Then I tried running this command in CMD

`c:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe" -e "rmarkdown::render('C:/file.rmd')`

and I get this error:

`Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).`

In RStudio I sent

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_available()

[1] TRUE
```

```
> rmarkdown::pandoc_version()

[1] ‘2.7.3’
```

What am I missing here?

By the way, I'm on Win10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There might be an issue wit h Pandoc version, obviously. But maybe some library requires that older pandoc version, and the issue comes from you using Rmarkdown from outside Rstudio.

[This link has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny/29710643#29710643)

Go into Rstudio and type

`Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")`

Now take the output from the command above and put it here

`Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="OUTPUT FROM ABOVE COMMAND")`

Comment: Ok so I made a 2 line script :
`Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc")
rmarkdown::render(input = "file.rmd")`

Now with the CMD I just call this script and it works fine, thanks a lot !