# use rmarkdown::render to create an html, through r and .rmd, in Linux

Tags: html, r, linux, r-markdown, render

I have a .rmd script "MainScript.rmd" that refers to a second script "SubScript.rmd" through render() , to create a html file, as such:

```
render("SubScript.rmd", output_dir = "./Results/", output_file = paste0(species,"_SeasonOverlap.html"))
```

This works great in RStudio on my windows computer.  However, I would like to run those same scripts on linux (without RStudio) through a powershell script.  I have been able to run r scripts through .sh using:

```
Rscript MainScript.r
```

But have not been able to run a .rmd script.  Even when I convert MainScript to a .r (instead of .rmd), I can't get past running the line render().  I get the following error message:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

I have downloaded pandoc on the linux (now found under "/nfs/stak/users/jobird/pandoc") but I don't know how to make my MainScript.r recognize where pandoc is, or even if that is what I need to do. I have little experience with linux.

My goal is to create a html document through running the SubScript.rmd program, from the MainScript.r, on linux.

Comment: Does this stackoverflow answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny/29710643#29710643

Comment: Thanks for sharing the post. I did see it but I'm not using RStudio on Linux. Moreover, I do not seem to find the (or an).Renviron file in my Linux folders.

Comment: Chances are that your Linux distribution provides installation packages for pandoc. On Debian based systems it should be sufficient to issue the command sudo apt install  pandoc.

Comment: Pandoc is indeed installed in my linux folder, I just don't know how to get r to use/recognize/find it in the context of rmarkdown::render.