# R MarkDown Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found

Tags: r, pandoc

I'm using R Studios Cloud but I am suddenly experiencing difficulty knitting my markdown in any format (html, pdf & word).

This is the error I'm thrown when I press the knit button:

```
    pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ? 
    rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
    Execution halted
```

I then check if pandoc is installed via pandoc_available():

```
> pandoc_available()
[1] FALSE
```

False, so I try to install pandoc again? (I do not recall uninstalling it)

```
> installr::install.pandoc()
sh: 1: ifconfig: not found
Error in system("ifconfig", intern = TRUE) : error in running command
```

However, again I get another error for ifconfig: not found.

I am new to learning R and programming as a whole. I'm quite stumped. I have checked recent threads including popular solutions (linked below) to no avail.

I have also tried opening a new markdown file but still could not get knit to work.

I'd appreciate any help on this one.

[popular solution to resolve pandoc version 1.12.3 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432607/pandoc-version-1-12-3-or-higher-is-required-and-was-not-found-r-shiny/29710643#29710643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

Relaunch your project by clicking on the 3 dots in the upper right corner.

See thread [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pandoc-error-when-knitting-rmd/131131/3).

Seems to be a common error happening to a lot of r studio cloud users in the past 24 hours.