# dygraph in knitr not working

Tags: r, knitr, dygraphs

When trying to Knit my dygraph in R using Knitr:

```
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
```

I get the following error:

```
## Error in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$width): "\maxwidth" is not a
valid CSS unit (e.g., "100%", "400px", "auto")
```

Could anyone assist with how I can possibly fix this or what it means?

EDIT: Example code.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 

<<include=FALSE>>= 
library(knitr) 
options(width=55, formatR.arrow=TRUE, highlight=TRUE, scipen=1, digits=3, tidy=TRUE, comment='##') opts_chunk$set(fig.width=4, fig.height=4, fig.align='center', tidy=TRUE, highlight=TRUE, cache=TRUE, dev='tikz', fig.path='figure/', cache.path='cache/')
@ 

<<include=FALSE>>= 
  library(tikzDevice) 
@ 

<<>>= 
library(dygraphs) 
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures") 
@ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your OS and your default web browser?

Comment: Windows 7 and using chrome.

Comment: Would you please add a minimal version of your document to the question?

Comment: Minimum working examples are long for Knitr, but here follows:

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}




<<include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
options(width=55, formatR.arrow=TRUE, highlight=TRUE,
        scipen=1, digits=3,
        tidy=TRUE, comment='##')
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=4, fig.height=4, fig.align='center', tidy=TRUE, 
               highlight=TRUE, 
               cache=TRUE, dev='tikz', fig.path='figure/', cache.path='cache/')
               #error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
@


<<include=FALSE>>=
library(tikzDevice)
@

<<>>=
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures")
@

\end{document}

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: After playing around quite some time with `knitr` and `dygraphs` I'm not sure if there is a solution. To problem is, `dygraphs` doesn't create images (AFAIK) but delivers HTML output. When knitting to a HTML document, this works just fine. But I don't see a `knitr` solution that allows directly embedding `dygraphs` plots into a PDF. The only solution that comes to my mind is generating the HTML and extracting a PDF/PNG/whatever image from the browser.

Comment: Update: You could use `wkhtmltopdf` for the HTML --> PDF conversion, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11044051/2706569).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Starting from [**knitr** 1.13](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md) (not released yet), HTML widgets will be automatically converted to screenshots using the [**webshot**](https://github.com/wch/webshot) package when the output format is not HTML.

---

**dygraphs** is an R package based on **htmlwidgets** (http://htmlwidgets.org), which means it only works for HTML output (e.g. from R Markdown documents or Shiny apps). You cannot use any **htmlwidgets**-based packages in LaTeX documents.

Comment: Right, but isn't there a way to just save it as a static figure (after which I include a hyperlink to the dynamic figure?).

Comment: One way you may go is to use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` to save it as an HTML page, then use tools like PhantomJS to take a screenshot of it, and insert the screenshot into LaTeX.