# render leaflet plots as raster in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, knitr, r-markdown

I realize that this largely defeats the purpose of using an interactive `leaflet` map, but I'm writing a traditional paper book and I want to show how the `leaflet` package for R works. I'm writing the book in LaTeX and rendering with `knitr`. Is there a way to have a `leaflet` map render as a raster image such that it could be included in this book?

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(leaflet)
map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = -77.03673, lat = 38.89761)
```

Now if I try a chunk like:

```
<<>>=
map
@
```

I get this error:

```
Error in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$width): "\maxwidth" is not a valid CSS unit
(e.g., "100%", "400px", "auto")
```

Trying to save as a PNG doesn't work either:

```
<<>>=
png(filename = "test.png")
map
dev.off()
@
```

`map` doesn't inherit from `ggplot`, so `ggsave` won't work either.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Like `dygraph`, `leaflet` is based on `htmlwidgets`. According to [this answer by Yihui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31820519/2706569) "you cannot use any htmlwidgets-based packages in LaTeX documents". But read the comments, too; there might be workarounds.

Comment: That makes sense -- thanks for the link. The best solution I've found is to render in RStudio and then use the Export... feature and save as a PNG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been a recent question on [How to save Leaflet in RStudio map as png or jpg file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336898/how-to-save-leaflet-in-rstudio-map-as-png-or-jpg-file). If you don't mind installing [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), the code below should help you create static images from **leaflet** (or **mapview**) maps. The only thing left to do then is to not show the `saveWidget` and `webshot` code in your book and instead import and display the png file created therefrom.

```
## install 'webshot' package
library(devtools)
install_github("wch/webshot")

## load packages
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(webshot)

## create map
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = -77.03673, lat = 38.89761)

## save html to png
saveWidget(m, "leaflet_map.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
webshot("leaflet_map.html", file = "leaflet_map.png",
        cliprect = "viewport")

## optionally display image when using knitr
# p <- knitr::include_graphics("leaflet_map.png")
```

And here is some LaTeX output for demonstration purposes. If anyone is interested, the complete .Rnw source file is available from [GitHub](https://github.com/fdetsch/snippets/blob/master/mapview/map_in_latex/png_in_latex.Rnw).

[image: LaTeX]

Comment: Great answer. You could add `knitr::include_graphics("leaflet_map.png")`, which is the only additional code required to use your approach in a `knitr` document.

Comment: You people are awesome.

Comment: That's it @CL. Or use `includegraphics` (from **graphicx**) or the like directly in the LaTeX code as I've done in the source file linked above.

Comment: @fdetsch I'd recommend `knitr::include_graphics()`, because it is agnostic of the output format (LaTeX, Markdown, whatever). I have also been working on automating this process of snapshotting HTML widgets when the output format is not HTML. Hopefully things will be much easier in the near future.

Comment: FYI, the work has been done in the current development version of **knitr**: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md