# save heatmap generated by d3heatmap

Tags: r, knitr, d3heatmap

I'm trying to save a heatmap produced by [`d3heatmap`](https://github.com/rstudio/d3heatmap) to a pdf file, but the file is always damaged.

```
library(d3heatmap)
pdf(file="heat.pdf")
d3heatmap(mtcars, scale = "column", colors = "Spectral")
dev.off()
```

I suspect the challenge is "this is an R package that implements a heatmap htmlwidget." However, I figured I could still capture the image produced because "Like any htmlwidget, you can visualize a d3 heatmap directly from the R console."

I looked at the two output functions in the package, `renderD3heatmap` and `d3heatmapOutput`, but I don't think either one gets me where I want to go.

**Update**
I followed @hrbrmstr's advice to look into `knitr` and `webshot`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043244/using-webshot-within-knitr) about how to get them to play nice. Here's my latest attempt to produce an image file. I think I'm on the right track with [`screenshot.opts`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md), but I'm getting a file about a bad connection.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---
```{r, setup}
library(d3heatmap)
library(knitr) # dev't version knitr_1.12.22 (also dev't version of webshot 0.3)
```

```{r, screenshot.opts=list(file="webshot.png", cliprect="viewport", selector = NULL)}
d3heatmap(mtcars, scale = "column", colors = "Spectral")
```
````

Comment: Install the dev version of `knitr`. It has functionality from the new `webshot` package to facilitate this.

Comment: thanks for the tip, @hrbrmstr. investigating.

Comment: I don't see the `webshot` function in the development version of `knitr`, so I downloaded the `webshot` package directly. Seems like it wants me to feed it a URL. Any pointers to examples of folks using this package (or from within knitr if I'm doing something wrong) to capture this widget?

Comment: Um… https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md ? (it's clearly in knitr dev.

Comment: Separate example of just using webshot: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/vegalite/blob/master/R/phantom.r

Comment: thanks for the links. i was expecting to find a `webshot` function in the development version of `knitr`, but maybe I shouldn't have. going to play around with this.

Comment: i think i'm close to getting it to work in knitr, but i have a problem after following the instruction to install `webshot::install_phantomjs()`. i get the message: `phantomjs.exe has been installed to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/PhantomJS` however when i run, i get the error that `sh: ~/Library/Application Support/PhantomJS/phantomjs: No such file or directory`. i think that i need to update the path, but i'm not sure how.

Comment: I created a separate question about this problem. Will come back here once working to close the loop on how to capture the heatmap image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043244/using-webshot-within-knitr

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35550394/2706569

Comment: @EricGreen Did you eventually get this to work for you (i.e., successfully produce a PDF from the d3heatmap)?  It seems to be an unsolved problem.