# using webshot within knitr

Tags: r, phantomjs, knitr

In the process of trying to find a solution to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041601/save-heatmap-generated-by-d3heatmap) about saving a heatmap produced by `d3heatmap`, I encountered an unrelated problem using `webshot` within the [development version of `knitr`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/NEWS.md) (HT: [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr)).

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('yihui/knitr', build_vignettes = TRUE)
library(knitr)
```

After installing and loading the development version of `knitr`, I tried running the following `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
library(d3heatmap)
d3heatmap(mtcars, scale = "column", colors = "Spectral")
```
````

I was prompted to install phantomjs:

```
webshot::install_phantomjs()

phantomjs.exe has been installed to /Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/PhantomJS
```

I tried running the `.Rmd` file again, but I got this error:

```
sh: ~/Library/Application Support/PhantomJS/phantomjs: No such file or directory
Quitting from lines 7-9 (test.Rmd) 
Error in (function (url = NULL, file = "webshot.png", vwidth = 992, vheight = 744,  : 
  webshot.js returned failure value: 127
Calls: <Anonymous> ... html_screenshot -> in_dir -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I believe that the error is telling me that R can't find phantomjs.exe, but I see that it's located in the specified path. I know this screams stupid user error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/wch/webshot/issues/19) and has been fixed in the current [development version of **webshot**](https://github.com/wch/webshot).

Comment: great, @Yihui. I can confirm that I was able to run the file with development version of `knitr` depending on the development version of `webshot`.