# Static leaflet map markers cut off when knit to PDF in R markdown

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to produce a static map via the leaflet package so I can knit it to a PDF using markdown but the circle markers on the map keep getting cut off and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here is the code I used to generate the map in markdown:

```
{r leaflet, echo=FALSE,fig.align = 'center',message=FALSE}

site=c(1,4,5,7,6,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,26,27,28,30,31,32,33,34,35,38,39,40,42,43,44,46,47,48,50,51,52,53,54,56,55,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,69,70,71,72,73,75,76,74,77,78,79,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,96,95,97,98,99,100,101,102,105,106,107,108,109,110,112,113,114,115,116,117,119,120,122,123,121,124,125,126,126,128,129,131,132,133,135,136,137,138,139,141,140,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,156,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,168,169,170,172,173,171,174,175,177,178,180,181,182,184,185,186,187,189,190,192,193,194,196,197,198,201,200,202,203,204,206,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,240)

lat=c(43.66184,44.79494,45.10964,43.69858,43.70498,44.62863,43.47742,43.47189,43.4778,46.1,45.32731,43.70013,44.98749,45.16991,45.36598,45.05,43.46897,43.73095,45.14393,45.08514,45.34322,44.24378,43.83065,43.67648,43.408,43.39672,45.33459,44.98288,44.95615,44.65252,43.67452,43.73467,45.14016,43.83735,43.88855,45.04484,45.111,43.69183,45.37833,43.6472,45.26212,44.66697,43.51302,43.69985,43.42405,43.50834,44.95199,43.6919,43.63744,43.43144,44.69951,43.50658,45.13892,43.68822,44.69283,45.10628,44.68769,43.4204,43.68891,43.6772,43.66724,44.94892,43.673,45.40933,44.96536,45.72368,43.66106,44.68769,44.62727,44.62965,43.61895,45.20126,45.15177,45.01517,45.1233,45.1333,44.59527,44.95621,44.71402,45.14022,45.14101,43.641,45.12103,44.9856,43.63273,43.68505,43.64198,43.61047,45.25096,43.55112,43.69663,44.95698,44.58521,43.69835,44.97415,43.6186,43.69422,43.70401,43.62252,43.65461,43.62553,44.73491,45.1492,44.3334,43.42677,44.7083,44.5023,44.50182,45.20878,43.63436,45.71507,45.2669,45.11048,45.09923,45.1,45.0832,44.99921,43.48639,43.66999,43.67264,45.16516,44.69605,45.26793,45.12006,43.4647,44.61949,45,44.27258,43.59923,43.71557,44.61159,45.3667,43.62905,43.68616,44.2575,43.73882,45.3796,45.37942,43.49335,43.74912,43.63405,43.6772,44.61894,43.68241,43.70326,43.52035,43.50868,43.78343,43.72467,43.83205,43.50578,44.2605,45.2708,45.10362,45.10574,43.42055,44.97344,43.41084,44.58236,43.51516,44.61175,44.98887,43.63253,43.6283,45.33006,44.95833,44.97313,44.99147,43.47264,45.02376,43.50256,43.63685,43.633,45.38256,43.6296,44.97619,43.69172,44.95984,44.58356,45.41866,45.21372,44.97467,45.0073,43.67669,43.80858,43.52703,43.53301,44.61022,43.67633,44.60393,44.43992,43.51764,44.6325,44.60235,43.66345,44.99206,44.9766,44.93675,44.6167,44.70273,44.48513)

long=c(-65.82654,-66.76915,-64.25404,-65.9014,-65.90719,-65.7084,-65.6738,-65.67257,-65.6778,-64.9,-64.48189,-65.83812,-66.96382,-64.76276,-64.41178,-66.78266,-65.75105,-65.86791,-64.26228,-67.08128,-63.94631,-66.36808,-65.99769,-65.82789,-65.61631,-65.62322,-64.49627,-66.96304,-66.93141,-66.71888,-65.78074,-66.09383,-66.9969,-66.12741,-66.09718,-66.86069,-66.35931,-65.90693,-64.12124,-66.05395,-66.08877,-66.75014,-65.76929,-65.94188,-65.64708,-66.00485,-66.73269,-65.82077,-66.14861,-65.6245,-65.6109,-65.77518,-66.26114,-65.93082,-66.74722,-64.34153,-66.69499,-65.67671,-66.14406,-65.9948,-66.00251,-66.94392,-65.99518,-64.92706,-66.72582,-64.61453,-65.91562,-66.72309,-66.68641,-66.68477,-66.03735,-64.62047,-64.81232,-66.93072,-66.9964,-66.99933,-66.76369,-66.96656,-66.71938,-66.96113,-66.96551,-66.06152,-67.01127,-66.91766,-65.78451,-65.77797,-65.79008,-66.02289,-65.00188,-65.79455,-65.88197,-65.23964,-66.75834,-65.86214,-66.95249,-66.02373,-65.94689,-65.85686,-66.02926,-65.99359,-65.81501,-66.72604,-66.9577,-66.26667,-65.62647,-66.71053,-67.1013,-67.10187,-66.10616,-66.04112,-64.65026,-66.09046,-67.03546,-66.39665,-64.949,-64.9667,-66.90648,-65.98843,-66.05015,-66.05649,-66.23939,-66.71873,-66.07333,-66.54549,-65.98472,-66.76206,-66.99933,-66.31754,-66.02321,-65.89888,-66.81908,-64.332,-66.02703,-65.83184,-66.33866,-65.94848,-64.12557,-64.12941,-65.68482,-65.86594,-65.79096,-65.86615,-66.72928,-65.83945,-66.04713,-65.77216,-65.76416,-66.14067,-66.08676,-65.92331,-65.98543,-66.32979,-66.06732,-66.50543,-66.50797,-65.63906,-66.9132,-66.01256,-66.76968,-65.76324,-66.75236,-66.91457,-66.06356,-66.0573,-64.69175,-66.73,-66.90683,-66.94061,-65.71102,-66.93858,-65.77045,-65.82332,-65.82441,-64.21233,-65.82546,-66.90538,-65.8667,-66.7197,-66.76596,-64.92214,-66.10414,-66.92311,-65.13797,-66.01695,-66.00262,-65.76791,-65.77155,-66.84181,-65.97445,-66.84205,-66.01569,-65.78002,-66.69222,-66.80682,-65.86613,-66.87169,-66.70255,-66.73583,-66.83263,-66.7374,-66.85033)

data=data.frame(site,lat,long)

library(leaflet)

# start basemap (note the argument to hide the zoom buttons)
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomControl = FALSE)) %>% 
  
  # add ocean basemap
  addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.OceanBasemap) %>%
  
  # focus map in a certain area / zoom level
  setView(lng = -66.0418475, lat = 45.110292, zoom = 7) %>%
  
  # add inset map
  addMiniMap(
    tiles = providers$Esri.OceanBasemap,
    position = 'bottomright', 
    width = 100, height = 100,
    toggleDisplay = FALSE) %>%
  
  ### Add scale bar
  addScaleBar()%>%
  
  # add points (as circle markers)
  addCircleMarkers(data = data, ~long, ~lat,
                   weight = 0.5,
                   col = 'white', 
                   fillColor = 'blue',
                   radius = 10, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.9, 
                   stroke = T)
```

When I knit this to html I get a map that looks like this, which is what I want it to look like in the PDF:
[image]

But when I knit this to a PDF it looks like this, you can notice the circle markers are cut off near the bottom center.

[image]

I've tried messing around with the zoom level and the setView, neither of which have worked. I've also tried messing around with the fig.height/fig.width/out.height/out.width settings, none of which worked (and also created blank grey areas in the map which is a whole other can of worms I'm trying to figure out).

I realize I should probably use a map package that isn't interactive like leaflet but at this point I've come too far so I would like to figure out why this is happening. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

### UPDATE: sessionInfo() output

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    
LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.4-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] pillar_1.5.0      compiler_4.0.3    tools_4.0.3       digest_0.6.27     
evaluate_0.14     lifecycle_1.0.0   tibble_3.0.4      gtable_0.3.0     
[9] lattice_0.20-41   pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_0.4.10      DBI_1.1.1         
yaml_2.2.1        xfun_0.19         dplyr_1.0.4       stringr_1.4.0    
[17] knitr_1.31        generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.5       grid_4.0.3        
tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2        R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.4.1      
[25] rmarkdown_2.7     purrr_0.3.4       tidyr_1.1.2       ggplot2_3.3.3     
magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      ellipsis_0.3.1    htmltools_0.5.1.1
[33] ggthemes_4.2.4    assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_2.0-0  utf8_1.1.4        
stringi_1.5.3     munsell_0.5.0     crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce your maps. Setting `setView(..., zoom = 6)` fixed the issue. Can you please run `sessionInfo()` and edit your question with its output?. Also, are you using any latex template or package in the `YAML` header?

Comment: Reducing the zoom does work but unfortunately I need it to be more zoomed in than that. It seems as though anything within a certain distance from the border is getting cut off because if I zoom in really far some of the top right points get cut off too. I don't believe I am using a latex template or package in the YAML header, but I could definitely be wrong as I am quite new to markdown and am still trying to wrap my brain around how it works. I'll post the output to sessionInfo() above though, thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone else runs into this issue, I was able to fix the problem by using the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527206/render-leaflet-plots-as-raster-in-r