# Is it possible in RStudio to speed up the PDF preview in Sumatra after compiling?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc, miktex

I had to reinstall everything on my computer.
After reinstallation of R, Rstudio, Pandoc and MikTex, the preview of knitted PDFs using RStudio and Sumatra takes a VERY long time. Prior to the reinstallation, the whole process tok only a few seconds. Now I have to wait more than thirty seconds for the Sumatra preview to be completed. The process somehow halts for a while between the

```
output file: MyFile.knit.md
```

and

```
Output created: volatility2.pdf
```

part of the output being printed in the R Markdown console.

I'm using the <kbd>Knit to PDF</kbd> option in RStudio, and I'm on a windows 7 64 bit system. I'm hoping some of you have a few suggestions, because this little hickup really messes up my workflow. The same problem occurs for all .Rmd files I've tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `knit` while working on the document to preview the final output, there might be a workaround:

RStudio will soon release a new document type called `html_notebook`, which is already available in the [preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/). Unlike standard `.rmd` files, notebooks are not `knit`but `preview`ed:

> Ordinary R Markdown documents are “knit”, but notebooks are “previewed”. While the notebook preview looks similar to a rendered R Markdown document, the notebook preview does not execute any of your R code chunks; it simply shows you a rendered copy of the markdown in your document along with the most recent chunk output. This preview is generated automatically whenever you save the notebook ... [[source](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html)].

This means that you are able to see the output instantly, as the notebook updates changes to your `.rmd` file, rather thank knitting the entire document.

As [Jonathan McPherson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347549/jonathan) points out in the comments section of [this manual](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html), the notebooks were designed so that you can simply replace `html_notebook` with e.g., `pdf_document` for seamless transition between file formats.

In other words, you could use the notebook format while working on the file, and only knit the document once after changing `html_notebook` to `pdf_document` for your final version (for automated conversion see e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043954/4798582)).